Embedding a twitchTV iframe into a page displayed by MAUI webview
I am having trouble displaying an iframe containing twitchTV strea, in a MAUI webview, and I was hoping someone could help me.
THIS works just fine:
View:
<WebView x:Name="WebViewForStreams" Source="{Binding StreamHtml}" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="400" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />

VM:
    public partial class LiveStreamVM : VMBase
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _streamHtml = null;

        public LiveStreamVM(IUserDialogs dialogs, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Log log) : base(dialogs, exceptionHandler, log)
        {
        }

        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            StreamHtml = "https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=haiset&parent=mydomain.xy";
        }

        public void OnDisappearing()
        {
            StreamHtml = null;
        }
    }

But I want to display my own page, and only socket the twitch frame into it. But, when I change it to this:
V:
                <WebView x:Name="WebViewForStreams" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="400" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <WebView.Source>
                        <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding StreamHtml}"/>
                    </WebView.Source>
                </WebView>

VM:
    public partial class LiveStreamVM : VMBase
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _streamHtml = null;

        public LiveStreamVM(IUserDialogs dialogs, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Log log) : base(dialogs, exceptionHandler, log)
        {
        }

        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            StreamHtml = MockPage();
        }

        private string MockPage()
        {
        
            return @"
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<iframe
    src=""https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=haiset&parent=mydomain.xy""
    height=""400""
    width=""400""
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>";
        }

        public void OnDisappearing()
        {
            StreamHtml = null;
        }
    }

I get following result:

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I imagine if you read their TOS they probably prohibit this, which is why they are blocking the request

But what exactly would be the offense? How is the example 1 and 2 different?

One is contained in an iframe and the other isn’t.  This a pretty common thing that many sites actively prohibit

Oh, yeah but twitch has this way of integrating twitch actively in their API tutorial: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips/

Well, turns out, you CAN embedd the twitch window in an iframe,but the whole page you're rendering the iframe in, has to come from a domain you specified in a "&parent=mydomain.xy" of the twitch URL.
If it doesn't, your browser will intentionally block this for security reasons, thinking this is some sort of an XSS attack.
